# Вызов конструктора базового класса при инициализации бина в Spring

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. У меня возник такой вопрос: допустим у меня в конфиге определен бин класса Achild. Есть также класс Aparent - родитель Achild. Вопрос - всегда ли при создании бина Achild будет также вызываться и конструктор Aparent ? И для чего вообще Spring это делает?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спринг здесь ни при чем, это фундаментальное положение в Java: каждый конструктор каждого класса (кроме `java.lang.Object`) всегда вызывает сначала конструктор своего предка, а тот своего и так далее.

**UPD**
Нет, это относится ко всем конструкторам. Компилятор сам подставляет вызов родительского конструктора, если вы не делаете этого вручную:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        // super(); - этот вызов компилятор вставит автоматически
        System.out.println("It's A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        // super(); - и этот тоже
        System.out.println("It's B");
    }
}
```

Вызов `new B();` приведет к выводу

```
It's A
It's B
```

Вы также можете вставить вызов `super()` сами, в том числе вызов любого другого родительского конструктора, не только без параметров. Есть еще нюанс, когда вы получите ошибку компиляции, если компилятор вставит вызов `super()` за вас, а в родительского классе такого конструктора нет ([@Nikolay Artamonov](/users/1372/nikolay-artamonov) ответил бы вам подробно и с примерами, для полного раскрытия темы тут нужно много писать). А вообще, про это стоит почитать, так как использовать Spring без понимания фундаментальных концепций Java неблагоразумно.

Comment: я имел в виду что у родительского класса *автоматически* может быть вызван только конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: а, ну почти да - вызовется конструктор без параметров - по умолчанию или собственноручно написанный.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос - (Есть еще нюанс, когда вы получите ошибку компиляции, если компилятор вставит вызов super() за вас, а в родительского классе такого конструктора нет) - а разве конструктор по умолчание не генерируется автоматически ? разве его обязательно нужно определять даже просто пустым ?

Comment: если нет пустых полей ожидающих определения то конструктор не обязателен